# how to get any integer in a sorted array of size n that appear more than n/k times, given that 0 < k < n, and in O(k log n) time in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

we need to find any integer in a sorted array appearing more than `n/k` in java, if not return -1. How it is possible in `klogn` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your input has 100,000 items in it, and we pick `k = 10`, as in, n/k is 10,000, as in, you're looking for the same number to be in the list 10,000 times.

Given that the list is sorted, if a number is 10k times in there, it'll be consecutive (all next to each other).

In basis then, you just need to look at `list[0]` and `list[10000]` and check if the same number is in both indices. If yes, trivially you have your answer. If no, check `list[20000]` and check if that is the same as what we just read at `list[10000]`. If yes, great, we have an answer. If no, take what's at `list[20000]` and use that to check it against `list[30000]`, and so on, until getting to the end.

You only need `k` steps for this, so this algorithm is `O(k)`. But it has a small problem - you can be 'unlucky' and miss a valid answer. Imagine that there is indeed a number in this list (let's say `18`) that shows up 10,005 times, however, the indices of these 10005 occurrences are `[9000, 19005]`. Our algorithm checks index 0, 10000, and 20000, and only finds this number at 10000 and would thus incorrectly report 'no number found'.

How 'bad' can it get? Only 'half' - if the algorithm instead checks twice as often (so not indices 0, 10k, 20k, 30k, etc, but indices 0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, etc), then it's not possible to 'miss', in the sense that any valid answer will result in *at least* 2 lookups having the same number. In this example, `lookup[10000]` and `lookup[15000]` both give you 18 - no matter how unlucky you are, you can no longer "miss it". However, if you now find a 'hit' (2 consecutive checked indices have the same number), you're not sure. If `list[10000]` is 18 and `list[15000]` is also 18, but `list[20000]` is not, is it a match? Could be - depends.

We've now changed the question: Instead of 'give me any number that shows up at least 10000 times in the list', it is now: 'is 18 at least 10000 times in this list?'.

That algorithm is *much* easier. Just use binary search to find the start and end indices and subtract those and you know how long the 'run' is. Binary search is an `O(log n)` algorithm.

This sticks an `O(log n)` algorithm inside an `O(k)` algorithm, thus giving you an algorithmic complexity of `O(k log n)`, as asked for.